# How do you get and display the Validation Rule Text field?

Tags: validation

I'm currently implementing a custom validation logic, and I'm planning to leverage the existing fields of the Validation Rule template such as the Text field to be used as an error message. Is this possible? if yes how do you get the values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will see the implementation of the method called `this.GetText()`, that you are using under your custom validation logic, it looks like this.

```
protected virtual string GetText(string text, params string[] arguments)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) text, nameof (text));
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) arguments, nameof (arguments));
  string str = string.Empty;
  Database database = Context.Database;
  if (database == null && this.ItemUri != (ItemUri) null)
    database = Factory.GetDatabase(this.ItemUri.DatabaseName, false);
  Item obj = database == null ? (Item) null : database.GetItem(this.ValidatorID);
  if (obj != null)
    str = obj[StandardValidator.textFieldId];
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    str = this.Parameters["Text"];
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    text = str;
  return Translate.Text(text, (object[]) arguments);
}
```

So it first checks for the `ValidatorID` variable using this.

```
Item obj = database == null ? (Item) null : database.GetItem(this.ValidatorID)
```

If it gets the Item, then it checks for the `textFieldId` and i.e. this

```
private static readonly ID textFieldId = new ID("{5DCF6FF3-41C5-466C-AD5E-991CFCD55716}");
```

If you see this field in the CMS, you will see that this is the ID for the field that you are looking for. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

And if this field is blank then it does the further operations.

So I think you need to pass the value in `this.ValidatorID` variable and it should get the value of the text field that you want to use.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Does this get the value of the Text field? for example in this item /sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/Common/Is Integer? 
Tried running the code but I got error on this line:
str = obj[StandardValidator.textFieldId]; it says StandardValidator doesnt have definition for textFieldId.

Comment: Did you check that what item you are getting in `obj` and does it contain the field you are looking for?

Comment: Database points to core, while obj is null

Comment: what you are passing in this.ValidatorID?

Comment: {D3BCF474-92AB-4BF4-8508-5D6881F0ED0E} which is the guid of my custom validation rule.

Comment: Okay, The method I have added above is the OOTB implementation from the Sitecore DLL. And it works fine with OOTB validations. So I would suggest that you need to add the same in your custom validation class and debug it by passing the master database. If it is getting your validation rule item, then it should get the text filed for sure.

Comment: Thanks, when I pointed the DB to master, I was able to get the field's value. the this.ValidatorID was the key.

Comment: Basically this worked for me:
            Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(this.ItemUri.DatabaseName, false);
            Item obj = database == null ? (Item)null : database.GetItem(this.ValidatorID);
            
            string str = string.Empty;
            if (obj != null)
                str = obj.Fields["Text"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                str = this.Parameters["Text"];

Comment: @Borj Please accept the answer if you think it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `Text` property from the `BaseValidator` class to get or set the validation text. (You'll have to make your custom validator class inherit the `StandardValidator`)

Here's a sample code. I hope it'll help :)

```
    public class MyCustomValidator : StandardValidator
    {
        public override string Name => "My Custom Validator";


        protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
        {
            try
            {
                //do something
                if(valid)
                    return ValidatorResult.Valid;
                else
                {
                    //**Here you can directly get or set the validation text like this**
                    var text = Text;
                    Text = $"Oops! Your item has validation errors.{text}";
                    return GetMaxValidatorResult();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //do something
                return ValidatorResult.Unknown;
            }

        }

        protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
        {
            return GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Error);
        }
    }
```